# How to fake mouse hover state with developer console?

Tags: firefox

There is a popup box showing a mini version of the cart with a few products. I need to debug it but it only shows if the mouse is over the div with class `button dropdown-toggle`.

How can I fake the mouse hover so that the popup shows?

I tried it like this:

[image]

But it does not do anything.

I also tried to set `display` to `block`, but this did not helped too.

Comment: That's the way to simulate `hover` state. If you are not seeing the appropriate style, it means you activating hover on the appropriate element with the correct class